# .htaccess rewriting URL to add a character to a URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, amp-html

I'm doing this to fix an error with my AMP pages. I'm using the Automatic AMP plugin, and this plugin lets you access the AMP pages using 2 different methods

1. site.com/post/amp/
2. site.com/post/?amp

Using the AMP Page validator (https://validator.ampproject.org) I see that all AMP pages using just /amp/ get multiple errors, while /?amp is validated correctly.

Unfortunately, Google is checking /amp/ for all my pages, hence I'm getting tons of errors.

What I'd like to know is how to use the .htaccess redirect rule to add the ? to the AMP queries so all /amp/ requests are redirected (with a 301) to /?amp/

I'd appreciate suggestions on this. Thank you

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Please accept it if it did using the tick at the top left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/amp/$ /$1?amp [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect any URL ending in `/amp/` to the same but with `?amp` instead, which seems to be what you want. To go in your root `.htaccess` file.